# how to display pdf in custom webview xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i want to display pdf in webview from url using pdfjs, but i am getting empty view. here is my code

CustomWebView.cs

```
 public class CustomWebView : WebView
        {
            public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
                    returnType: typeof(string),
                    declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
                    defaultValue: default(string));

            public string Uri
            {
                get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
                set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
            }
        }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <local:CustomWebView Uri="http://veezo2007pkk.somee.com/api/DiagnosticDetail/RetrieveFile/1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

App.Android

CustomWebViewRenderer.cs

```
 public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}", string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri))));
            }
        }
    }
```

it seems look fine, but i dont know why its not showing in webview....

Comment: Do you have this pdf in your mobile internal storage or on some web link?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume two things here. One, you're not precious about PDF file being displayed in the `WebView`. Second you're OK with using 3rd party libraries.

I would suggest using [SyncFusion PdfViewer](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfpdfviewer/getting-started). It's very easy to use and does everything you might want to do with PDFs - maybe not everything but a lot. If you're worried that you will need to pay a lot for these controls, fear not! [SyncFusion has a free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense), which you can use (if you're not making more than a $1 mln USD and you don't have a larger team than 5 devs). You might want to have a look at [this thread](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/127016/load-pdf-from-url-in-pdfviewer), talking about showing PDF from URL.

Comment: do you have any code example, how to display binary data in syncfusion pdf viewer? becasue i have pdf data in database as binary format

Comment: Have a look at the Getting Started with PdfViewer (first link in my answer). You need to basically turn your data into a stream and bind it to the `InputFileStream` property on the `SfPdfViewer`

Comment: the problem its not free

Comment: Like I wrote in my answer, there's a community version - which is free. However, you do need to fulfil couple of conditions, which are listed in my answer as well.